# Converting CMSampleBuffer to CVMetalTexture in Swift with CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

Tags: swift, avfoundation, metal

I'm trying to get a simple render-camera-output-to-metal-layer pipeline going, and it works well enough in Objective-C (There's the MetalVideoCapture sample app) but there seems to be some formatting weirdness when I try to translate that to swift.  My ultrasimple capture buffer looks like this (ignore the lack of sanitization...)

```
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    var error: CVReturn! = nil
    let sourceImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(sourceImageBuffer!)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(sourceImageBuffer!)
    var outTexture: CVMetalTextureRef? = nil

    error  = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, videoTextureCache!, sourceImageBuffer!, nil, MTLPixelFormat.BGRA8Unorm, width, height, 0, &outTexture!)

    if error != nil {
        print("Error! \(error)")
    }

    let videoTexture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(outTexture!)
    self.imageTexture = videoTexture!
}
```

Where videoTextureCache is `var videoTextureCache: CVMetalTextureCache? = nil`

But it gives me `Cannot invoke 'CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage' with an argument list of type '(CFAllocator!, CVMetalTextureCache, CVImageBuffer, nil, MTLPixelFormat, Int, Int, Int, inout CVMetalTextureRef)'`

The thing is, if I replace outTexture with nil it stops throwing the error but clearly that's not going to help me.  According to the reference for the function I need UnsafeMutablePointer?> for that last value.  Which I'm not sure how to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to allocate the your the textureCache in advance, here is what I use as the member variable:

```
var _videoTextureCache : Unmanaged<CVMetalTextureCacheRef>?
```

And then I allocate the textureCache in an initialization method via

```
CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, _context.device, nil, &_videoTextureCache)
```

where _context.device is the MTLDevice. Then, in the captureOutput method, I use the following (beware, no error checking included here)

```
var textureRef : Unmanaged<CVMetalTextureRef>?
CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _videoTextureCache!.takeUnretainedValue(), imageBuffer, nil, MTLPixelFormat.BGRA8Unorm, width, height, 0, &textureRef)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant! I've been wrestling with this too - thanks a million for this :)

Comment: This answer is out of date. See @XueYu's answer for Swift 3 and Swift 4.

Answer (score 3):

Update @peacer212 answer to Swift 3.

You don't need `Unmanaged` and `takeUnretainedValue` anymore. So the code should be:

```
var textureCache: CVMetalTextureCache?

...
CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, _context.device, nil, &_videoTextureCache)

...

var textureRef : CVMetalTexture?
CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache!, imageBuffer, nil, .bgra8Unorm, width, height, 0, & textureRef)
```

Comment: What is videoTextureCache?